# Trouble understanding a step in a proof, algebra with summation

Tags: proof-explanation

I have this line in a proof that I do not understand and would like some help understanding please.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2-n\bar{x}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^2-2x_i\bar{x}+\bar{x}^2)$$

Can anybody enlighten me on this transformation please?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any hypotheses on the $x_i$s?

Comment: what is $\bar{x}$?

Comment: yes, $\bar{x_i}$ is the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\bar x$ is the average $\bar x = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, then 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n 2x_i \bar x = 2\bar x \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 2n \bar x ^2.
$$
Furthermore, 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \bar x^2 = \bar x^2 \sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n\bar x ^2
$$

Comment: Oh, nice, now I get it. Thanks @Kusma